# Induction and Recursion: $F(1) = 2$ and $F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) + \dotsb + F(1) + 2$, $n \ge 2$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recursion

We have this:

$F(1) = 2$

$F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) + \dotsb + F(1) + 2$, $n \ge 2$

And we need:

1) give a recursive definition of $F(n)$

2) prove using mathematical induction that for every positive integer $n$, $F(n) = 2^n$.

Comment: The definition you've been given for $f(n)$ _is_ the recursive definition, no?

Comment: Your (2) can't be right, since $F(3) = F(2) + F(1) + 2 = 4 + 2 + 2 = 8$.  Probably the exponent got mangled on C&P and you meant $2^n$.

Comment: @BillWallis, probably what is sought in (1) is a 'one-step' recursion, like $F(n) = 2F(n - 1)$.

Comment: @LSpice Ah yes, that would make sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) + \dotsb + F(1) + 2$$

$$F(n+1) = F(n)+ F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) + \dotsb + F(1) + 2$$

so,

$$F(n+1)-F(n)=F(n)$$ 
$$F(n+1)=2F(n)$$

Is it suggest you something?

Comment: $=2^n by   supposition   =2^n+2^n=2^n (1+1)=2*2^n=2^(+1)$
Am i right or doing it all wrong?

Comment: @SANDRO: That is the idea